# Get two color effect into round img

Tags: html, css

I am working on this project
https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/todo-app-Su1_KokOW

I am having problem to get the mixed color into the round img for checking the note as in the picture[check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwFjm.png)

Maybe there is some kind of properties that I miss ??
Can please anyone give me some advice?

```css
.circle-image {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: hsl(237, 14%, 26%);
  margin-left: 6%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  background-color: ??????;
  border-color: white;
  border: .1px white solid;
}

.circle-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="check"> <span class="circle-image"> <img id="img" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" width="0" height="0" alt="" />  </span>
```

Comment: you are looking for gradient

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS gradient. It can generated in any "CSS Gradinet Generator" in Google. **You don't need a image for this task.**
Its look like this:

```
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest and best solution here is to use a background gradient.

I'm probably not spot on with your colors, but if you change `background-color` in your CSS to be a gradient, it will work:

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #9d78e5 0%, #7eb8ef 100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for gradient background.
You can add background with linear-gradient property:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);
```

Here you play with it:
https://cssgradient.io/